# Having trouble with getting an image to fit on a face of a cube

Tags: unity, textures, mesh, virtual-reality

I have a problem with a Unity project that I'm working on. I'm creating an 3D art gallery which will be developed into a VR application in the future.

In a 3D scene, I have created a `paint canvas` `GameObject` (a cube) but I have some trouble getting images fit on the whole `canvas`. When I try to apply an image as a material, it is treated as a texture and only a small part of the image is visible on the `canvas`.

I am planning to make a UI where the user can upload pictures and the application will automatically render the gallery with these pictures.

[image: I drag and dropped a Mona Lisa image to the plane]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the material on your cube, and a screenshot of what it looks like in game, compared to the original image?

Comment: @DMGregory I uploaded a screenshot. This is what happens when I drag and drop the Mona Lisa image to plane.

Comment: That's one the two things I asked you for. Can you also ensure you show us your material configuration, and import settings on your texture?

Comment: Done. Although I did not configure the martial properties like a texture. Just  dropped it on the canvas. I need to know is there a way I can show any image in full size and fit in to the size of canvas frame.